# como crear una excepcion correctamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
elementos = [1, 5, -2]

def agregar_una_vez(self):
    try: 
        elementos.append(self)
        for i in elementos:
            if i == self:
                raise ValueError()

    except  ValueError:
        print("Error: Imposible añadir elementos duplicados => [elemento].")

agregar_una_vez(1)
print(elementos)
```

Debo crear una funcion donde se agreguen elementos a mi lista y si se agrega un elemento que ya esta en  lista, debe generar un error.

He intentado esto pero no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Que no te funciona exactamente? acabo de probar tu codigo y me muestra tanto el error como los elementos agregados. Eso si,  salta el error pero el elemento lo agrega al array.

Comment: Cual es el error o comportamiento NO esperado que sucede? Como está tu código, debería de generar el error y a la vez agregar el elemento sin importar que esté o no repetido.

Comment: Estas agregando los elementos ' elementos.append(self) ' directamente sin verificar si ya existe, luego estas comprobando si existe, pero ya están agregados.

Comment: independientemente del valor que añada ala lista me muestra el texto de la excepción creada, además como hago para que no se añada el numero si ya esta en la lista

Answer (score 5):

En tu código tienes inmediatamente después del `try` que añada el número en `elementos`, y es algo que puede hacer independientemente de que ya esté en la lista o no, por eso lo hace siempre.

Podrías evitarlo por ejemplo poniendo que lo añada si `i` no es igual a `self`, y saliendo del bucle si se da el caso (para que no lo añada varias veces).

```
    else:
        elementos.append(self)
        break
```

De todas formas, puedes hacerlo simplemente mirando si el número está en la lista y que imprima el error si está o que lo añada si no está:

```
elementos = [1, 5, -2]

def agregar_una_vez(elemento):
    if elemento in elementos:
        print(f"Error: Imposible añadir elementos duplicados => {elemento}")
    else:
        elementos.append(elemento)

agregar_una_vez(1)
print(elementos)
```

En este caso para un 1 (que ya está en la lista), devolverá:

```
Error: Imposible añadir elementos duplicados => 1
[1, 5, -2]
```

Si le pasas por un número que no está, `agregar_una_vez(4)` devolverá:

```
[1, 5, -2, 4]
```

Con `if elemento in elementos` evalúa si el numero está en la lista. Si está imprime el mensaje, si no está añade el número.

Por otro lado, estás poniendo como argumento de la función `self`, y aunque te va a funcionar igual, deberías dejar esta palabra para los métodos de las clases para no liarte.